# How to Combine D3's built in zoom as well as on click zoom for Zoomable Icicle?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently using the Zoomable Icicle layout example found here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1005873 to view a file system.

The example provides a "zoom" on click, but I would also like to incorporate D3's zoom behaviour on the graph as well.

I am worried that these two zoom functions will clash on click, so do I need to reset D3's zoom behaviour on click?

How can I incorporate both these zoom-like functions that they do not conflict and rather provide smooth interaction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without speculating on the use case for this, I was curious to see how this would **pan** out (no pun intended). Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UZRxT/) with the results...not sure what to think, honestly...but my brains get fried on Fridays anyways.

```
function zoom() {
    d3.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

One thing is true...panning helps :)

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DvX9W/) Per request, this version has a Reset Zoom button that resets the zoom AND the zoomable icicle to its initial display (with transition).

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this example! It gives me a starting point to work from...I would just like to know, is there a way to place the graph in its original position and at its original zoom scale at click so that it first "resets" before it zooms in using the click functionality?

Comment: @user2651192 Yes, please see the updated fiddle in my just-edited answer above.